# Exposing multiple objects with RMI in Spring

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring, rmi

How do I expose multiple objects with RMI using Spring?

I start with what is written [here](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/remoting.html#remoting-rmi-server).

What if I want to expose more objects, must I declare another instance of RMIServiceExporter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you need to declare an instance of RMIServiceExporter for each service you wish to expose. Each RMIServiceExporter can only be associated with a single service instance and service interface.

Comment: This answer is partial. Does it mean that each exported service must be bound to its own port?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 for each RMIServiceExporter you can specifiy the RMI registry port but there would only be a single RMI registry so they would share the same port. You'd only override if using a port that differs from the default of 1099.